# SQL/MySQL: split a quantity value into multiple rows by date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-warehouse

I have a table with three columns: `planning_start_date - planning_end_date - quantity`.

For example I have this data:

```
 planning_start_date | planning_end_date | quantity
          2019-03-01 |        2019-03-31 |     1500
```

I need to split the value 1500 into multiple rows with the adverage per day, so 1500 / 31 days = 48,38 per day.

The expected result should be:

```
date         daily_qty
2019-03-01 |     48,38
2019-03-02 |     48,38
2019-03-03 |     48,38
...
2019-03-31 |     48,38
```

Anyone with some suggestions?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Nick I am in production with MySQL 5.7.26 and for the moment I don't want to change. Even though I saw that with MySQL 8 I could use something like `WITH RECURSIVE`. I all cases, also with MySQL 8, I have not been able to write the query.

Comment: Do you want those expected multiple rows for each row in your table?  Or do you want it summed by date?  If the latter, show example data and expected results when there are multiple row with overlapping planning date ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you decide to upgrade to MySQL 8.0, here's a recursive CTE that will generate a list of all the days between `planning_start_date`  and `planning_end_date` along with the required daily quantity:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT planning_start_date AS date, 
           planning_end_date, 
           quantity / (DATEDIFF(planning_end_date, planning_start_date) + 1) AS daily_qty
    FROM test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date + INTERVAL 1 DAY, planning_end_date, daily_qty
    FROM cte
    WHERE date < planning_end_date
)
SELECT `date`, daily_qty
FROM cte
ORDER BY `date`
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a397410cf7ce04efb1fea1b6e14148d)

Answer (score 1):

In MySLQ 8+, you can use a recursive CTE like this:

```
with recursive cte(dte, planning_end_date, quantity, days) as (
      select planning_start_date as dte, planning_end_date, quantity, datediff(planning_end_date, planning_start_date) + 1 as days
      from t
      union all
      select dte + interval 1 day as dte, planning_end_date, quantity, days
      from cte
      where dte < planning_end_date
     )
select dte, quantity / days
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fa3ca1d381ec4607b040f472ea3019c6) is a db<>fiddle.

In earlier versions, you want a numbers table of some sort.  For instance, if your table has enough rows, you can just use it:

```
select (planning_start_date + interval n.n day),
       quantity / (datediff(planning_end_date, planning_start_date) + 1)
from t join
     (select (@rn := @rn + 1) as n
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) n
     on planning_start_date + interval n.n day <= planning_end_date;
```

You can use any table that is large enough for `n`.