# SQL Date with x amount of open orders

Tags: mysql

I have 3 columns. Customer | Order Placed | Order Delivered | Order#
I would like to know the total amount of open orders per day per customer for the past 2 years.

so if we have a table like

| Customer | Order Placed | Order Delivered | Order# |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mills | 2021-05-04 | 2021-05-06 | #1 |
| Mills | 2021-05-05 | 2021-05-07 | #2 |
| Mart | 2021 05-06 | 2021-05-08 | #3 |

I would expect something like this to be returned

| Day | Customer | Open Orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-04 | Mills | 1 |
| 2021-05-05 | Mills | 2 |
| 2021-05-06 | Mills | 2 |
| 2021-05-07 | Mills | 1 |
| 2021-05-06 | Mart | 1 |
| 2021-05-07 | Mart | 1 |
| 2021-05-08 | Mart | 1 |

I can do this very easily using a Procedure and inserting the dates into a temporary table. The issue here is that I am not allowed to create procedures nor temp tables in the query to the db. If anyone knows of a workaround I would be very thankful.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass That question is SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Very easy to do a search, whether it's MS- or MySQL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59356058/sql-mysql-split-a-quantity-value-into-multiple-rows-by-date. If one has a learning attitude instead of [using Stackoverflow as a coding service](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

So something like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(order_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,customer varchar(12) 
,date_ordered DATE
,date_delivered DATE
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'Mills','2021-05-04','2021-05-06'),
(2,'Mills','2021-05-05','2021-05-07'),
(3,'Mart','2021-05-06','2021-05-08');
```

...

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(n) AS 
(SELECT MIN(date_ordered) FROM my_table
 UNION
 SELECT n + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM cte WHERE n < (SELECT MAX(date_delivered) FROM my_table)
)
SELECT n dt 
     , x.customer
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM cte
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table x
    ON cte.n BETWEEN x.date_ordered AND x.date_delivered
 GROUP
    BY dt, customer
 ORDER
    BY customer DESC,dt;
    
+------------+----------+-------+
| dt         | customer | total |
+------------+----------+-------+
| 2021-05-04 | Mills    |     1 |
| 2021-05-05 | Mills    |     2 |
| 2021-05-06 | Mills    |     2 |
| 2021-05-07 | Mills    |     1 |
| 2021-05-06 | Mart     |     1 |
| 2021-05-07 | Mart     |     1 |
| 2021-05-08 | Mart     |     1 |
+------------+----------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```